# Customize unpack from function python

Tags: python-3.x

I have one function (request_handler) that return a tuple type and lots of code need to code it to use partical of element for return, if there is a better way customize unpack so I do not have lots of duplicated code like following? or I should just use namedtuple? suggestion?

```
from typing import Tuple
def request_handler(data) -> Tuple[str]:
    "return a tuple type after some calculate from data
    ...
    "
    return name, address, school, zipcode, company
def callone(data):
    ...
    var, *- = request_handler(data)

def cal_school(data):
    ...
    _, _, var, *- = request_handler(data)

def cal_company(data):
    ...
    *_, var = request_handler(data)

def cal_person(data):
    ...
    name, add, *_ = request_handler(data)

def cal_zipcode(data):
    ...
    *_, code, _ = request_handler(data)
```

Comment: You can just use plain indexing like `school = the_tuple[2]`, or yes, use a namedtuple.

Comment: I would use a dictionary or a namedtuple, because indexing is the perfect way to both make the code hard to read and easy to break when you change the return order.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you should not return a tuple (as `return` value) of more than 2-3 items.
The greater number of those the higher chances to get an error-prone functionality with chances of confusing the unpacked items or their order.

You got a case with 5 attributes now. What if request payload contains 10 attributes???

As for `namedtuple`: that could be an option in case if such objects are not expected to be changed/modified across application. 
Python's `namedtuple` conceptually serves as *immutable* [Value object](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value_object).
Try `namedtuple`, and in case if it won't *pull its weigh* - consider designing a custom class (*Record*).